# Why does the "save" return true, but database has a void record?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I have written a Rails app that communities with front end by json-rpc. The ActiveRecord Class is:

```
class ProcessingDocument < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :command, :comment, :creator, :emergency_level, :file_name, :is_locked, :is_removed, :last_status, :next_status, :owner_id, :paper_title, :receiver, :sender, :status, :suggest, :unit_id, :uuid, :workflow_id
  attr_accessor :command, :comment, :creator, :emergency_level, :file_name, :is_locked, :is_removed, :last_status, :next_status, :owner_id, :paper_title, :receiver, :sender, :status, :suggest, :unit_id, :uuid, :workflow_id

  def self.all_propertoes
    [:command, :comment, :creator, :emergency_level, :file_name, :is_locked, :is_removed, :last_status, :next_status, :owner_id, :paper_title, :receiver, :sender, :status, :suggest, :unit_id, :uuid, :workflow_id]
  end
end
```

And the Controller dynamic updates the object of ProcessingDocument by json.

```
def pd_create(json)
    pd_now = ProcessingDocument.new(:uuid => generate_uuid)
    json["params"].each do |k, v|   # the json["params"] is a Hash
        if ProcessingDocument.all_propertoes.include? k.to_sym
            pd_now.send("#{k}=", v)
        else
            render json: default_fail_json(json, __method__)
            return
        end
    end

    if pd_now.save
        debug_method pd_now.to_json  # this is a stdout bebug

        result = { :uuid => pd_now.uuid }
        render json: respond_data(json, result, nil)
    else
        render json: default_fail_json(json, __method__)
    end
end
```

When I post a json `{"status":"1", "command":"stuff"}`, the `debug_method` print:

```
{"command":"stuff","comment":null,"created_at":"2012-12-11T12:02:41Z",
"creator":null,"emergency_level":null,"file_name":null,"id":16,"is_locked":null,
"is_removed":null,"last_status":null,"next_status":null,"owner_id":null,
"paper_title":null,"receiver":null,"sender":null,"status":"1","suggest":null,
"unit_id":null,"updated_at":"2012-12-11T12:02:41Z",
"uuid":"21403d30-c2c1-4fc8-94ba-36d059fdc170","workflow_id":null}
```

But the database don't save the "command", ,"status" and "uuid" :

```
Started POST "/services/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-11 20:02:41 +0800
Processing by ServicesController#accept as JSON
Parameters: {"{\"id\":\"7e330302-dede-4d2f-bf52-8e90174bb837\",\"method\":\"pd_create\",\"params\":{\"status\":\"1\",\"command\":\"stuff\"}}"=>nil}
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "processing_documents" ("command", "comment", "created_at", "creator", "emergency_level", "file_name", "is_locked", "is_removed", "last_status", "next_status", "owner_id", "paper_title", "receiver", "sender", "status", "suggest", "unit_id", "updated_at", "uuid", "workflow_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["command", nil], ["comment", nil], ["created_at", Tue, 11 Dec 2012 12:02:41 UTC +00:00], ["creator", nil], ["emergency_level", nil], ["file_name", nil], ["is_locked", nil], ["is_removed", nil], ["last_status", nil], ["next_status", nil], ["owner_id", nil], ["paper_title", nil], ["receiver", nil], ["sender", nil], ["status", nil], ["suggest", nil], ["unit_id", nil], ["updated_at", Tue, 11 Dec 2012 12:02:41 UTC +00:00], ["uuid", nil], ["workflow_id", nil]]
(2.5ms)  commit transaction
Completed 200 OK in 23ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 3.5ms)
```

You have see the SQL :`SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "processing_documents" ("command", "comment", "created_at", "creator", "emergency_level", "file_name", "is_locked", "is_removed", "last_status", "next_status", "owner_id", "paper_title", "receiver", "sender", "status", "suggest", "unit_id", "updated_at", "uuid", "workflow_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["command", nil], ["comment", nil], ["created_at", Tue, 11 Dec 2012 12:02:41 UTC +00:00], ["creator", nil], ["emergency_level", nil], ["file_name", nil], ["is_locked", nil], ["is_removed", nil], ["last_status", nil], ["next_status", nil], ["owner_id", nil], ["paper_title", nil], ["receiver", nil], ["sender", nil], ["status", nil], ["suggest", nil], ["unit_id", nil], ["updated_at", Tue, 11 Dec 2012 12:02:41 UTC +00:00], ["uuid", nil], ["workflow_id", nil]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you call `attr_accessor` on your model attributes?

```
attr_accessor :command, :comment, :creator, :emergency_level, :file_name, :is_locked, :is_removed, :last_status, :next_status, :owner_id, :paper_title, :receiver, :sender, :status, :suggest, :unit_id, :uuid, :workflow_id
```

These are creating accessor methods which set instance variables, e.g. `attr_accessor :command` does the equivalent of creating a method like this:

```
def command
  @command
end

def self.command=(value)
  @command = value
end
```

So what is happening in your code right now is that when you call `pd_now.send("#{k}=", v)` on each key/value in the hash, instance variables are being set rather than database attributes. That is why you are not seeing the attributes in the SQL generated after you call `save`.

To fix this, just remove the `attr_accessor` line in your model.

Ref: [Why use Ruby's attr_accessor, attr_reader and attr_writer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046831/why-use-rubys-attr-accessor-attr-reader-and-attr-writer)

Comment: Thank you very much!! But I can't understand the difference between `attr_accessor` of Ruby and `attr_accessible` of Rails.

Comment: There is a lot of confusion about these two methods, they in fact do very different things. See e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700785/using-attr-accessor-and-attr-accessible-on-the-same-field http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136420/difference-between-attr-accessor-and-attr-accessible