# Rails Create method resulting in Nil records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Why does this create method make a `nil` record?

I have tried:

> Dropdown.create(subject: "test")
>
> Dropdown.create({subject: "test", subject_value: "1"})
>
> Dropdown.create({:subject => "test", :subject_value => "1"})

All result in `nil` records.

```
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "dropdowns" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2016-01-21 23:58:04.979225"], ["updated_at", "2016-01-21 23:58:04.979225"]]
   (2.1ms)  commit transaction
=> #<Dropdown id: 145, subject: nil, visible: nil, subject_value: nil, subject_description: nil, created_at: "2016-01-21 23:58:04", updated_at: "2016-01-21 23:58:04
```

Model file

```
class Dropdown < ActiveRecord::Base
  
    FIELDS =  [
              :subject,
              :visible,
              :subject_value,
              :subject_description
            ]
  
  attr_accessor(*FIELDS)
  subjects = %w[math english spanish]
  
  subjects.each do |s|
    scope s.to_sym, -> { where(subject: s) }
  end

end
```

Migration file

```
class CreateDropdowns < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :dropdowns do |t|
      t.string :subject
      t.boolean :visible
      t.string :subject_value
      t.string :subject_description

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: you probably don't want `attr_accessor(*FIELDS)` in your model, you are looking for the wrath of ActiveRecord

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700785/using-attr-accessor-and-attr-accessible-on-the-same-field#answer-4735726 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793098/usage-of-attr-accessor-in-rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overriding your `ActiveRecord::Base` functionality by declaring `attr_accessor`:

```
#app/models/dropdown.rb
class Dropdown < ActiveRecord::Base

  subjects = %w(math english spanish)

  subjects.each do |s|
    scope s.to_sym, -> { where(subject: s) }
  end

end
```

1. You don't need to declare FIELDS -- you can call [`@model.attributes` (instance) or `Model.column_names` (class)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1291395/1143732) to get all the fields for that model.
2. [`attr_accessor`](http://rubyinrails.com/2014/03/17/what-is-attr_accessor-in-rails/) creates a set of [`getter`/`setter` methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737421/trying-to-learn-understand-ruby-setter-and-getter-methods) in the class. This overrides any attributes you may have from your db, which is why you're getting `nil` entries when you save. [Good ref here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html).

--

The above model should work for you.

Answer (score -1):

It is not necessary to use `attr_accessor` if these fields are columns of a table in your database. ActiveRecord done it for you.

Try to use `attr_accessible` instead of `attr_accessor`. But for rails 4+, not necessary to use it. see http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/attr_accessible

> This method is deprecated or moved on the latest stable version. The
>   last existing version (v3.2.13) is shown here.

Comment: how does the advice to use `attr_accessible` for a question with `ruby-on-rails-4` tag gets an upvote?

Comment: This does not answer the question, lifting an answer from the links I posted without understanding the consequences

Comment: Oops, my fault, just filter by ruby-on-rail tag