# Having trouble getting form field to have to database with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm new to Ruby/RoR and so far things have been going well, but I am having issues with updating the database from a form field (every field saves except the birthday field). I assume there is a minor implementation issue here but I'm having trouble working it out.

Form:

```
    <%= f.label :birthday %>
    <%= f.date_select :birthday, {order: [:month, :day, :year], prompt: { day: 'Select day', month: 'Select month', year: 'Select year' }, start_year: Date.today.year - 118, end_year: Date.today.year}, class: 'form-control' %>
```

User model:

```
    def update 
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      if @user.update_attributes(user_params) 
        flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
        redirect_to @user
      else 
        render 'edit'
      end
    end

    def user_params
      unless logged_in?
        params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :usertype, :password,:password_confirmation)
      else 
        params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :street, :city, :state, :zipcode,  :phone_number, :birthday, :month, :day, :year)
      end
    end
```

Database migration for field

```
    add_column :users, :birthday, :date
    add_column :users, :month, :date
    add_column :users, :day, :date
    add_column :users, :year, :date
```

Comment: do you have some pre-processing (before_save or before_create etc) in place in model?

Comment: Did you test whether the `else` block in `user_params` is firing?

Comment: What do you see if you print out the params at the top of the update method?

Comment: I had :birthday included in `attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token` and once I removed that it seems to save - can someone provide context as to why that was an issue? Is it just because the model was pulling nil from the database and setting that equal to :birthday before updating user_params (aka :birthday from the form was overrode by a nil value)?

Comment: @MA1 added an answer to explain that in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have `attr_accessor` for a field, it creates the virtual attributes which can be instantiated in context of Ruby `object` but does not map to the field of database.

In your case, since you have the database field `birthday` and you made the virtual attribute with same name, in `update` call, that attribute remained assigned to virtual attribute and not to the database field generated by ActiveRecord. Hence, your object wasn't saved.

`attr_accessor` in rails code is usually used when you do not have a corresponding field in database, but want to have attributes on object, say 'first_name`and`last_name`, where database has`full_name`.

Also, in context of Rails, `attr_accessor` is different from `attr_accessible`. Latter is often used to whitelist parameters for mass-assignment of attributes; it is replaced by Strong-parameters in newer version of Rails (which you are using)

Hope it helps :)

**Edit** : was searching if such question was asked around. Found this and think this will also be helpful to you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4735726/1376448

Comment: Great link -- thanks for the explanation and additional resource!

Comment: Thanks, I didn't!